# Why only the numerator is derived?

Tags: derivatives

Why the derivative of $y = \frac{x^5}{a+b}-\frac{x^2}{a-b}-x$ is solved by deriving just the numerators?

The solution is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{5x^4}{a-b}-\frac{2x}{a-b}-1$.

Comment: As $$\dfrac{d[a\cdot f(x)]}{dx}=a\cdot \dfrac{d[ f(x)]}{dx}$$ where $a$ is independent of $x$

Comment: Note: $x$ is different from $a,b$ because you are taking $\frac{d}{dx}$, the derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: To whom it may concern: please don't downvote questions because you think they're elementary.

Comment: $a, b$ are just constants. it like differentiating $\frac{x^5}{2} - \frac {x^2}3 - x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the denominator is constant, it's really easiest to apply the constant multiple rule.  That is, $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{c}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{c}f(x)=\frac1c f'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{c}$

If you insist on using the quotient rule, you get the same answer, as shown in marwalix's post.

Answer (score 2):

Because the denominator does not depend on $x$. So if we were to formally use $\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$ we get by plugging $v'=0$ ($v$ does not depend on $x$) $\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'}{v}$

Comment: But this would be a division by zero. That's why we ignore the constants in the denominator?

Comment: No there is no $v'$ in the denominator !

Comment: You're right. My mistake